# $\cos(\cos(\cos(\cos(\cos(\cos(\cos(....(\theta)))))))))$ approaches a constant as the number of cosines increases

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, graphing-functions, trigonometric-series

I was experimenting with the software [geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/classic), and playing with a couple of unusual trigonometric functions and I encountered a quite strange phenomena when I entered this input -
$$f(\theta)=\cos(\cos(\cos(\cos(\cos(\cos(\cos(....(\theta)))))))))$$
Let's assume the number of cosines approach infinity, though my input was 10-20 cosines.

I asked the program to graph this function and surprisingly the graph was straight-lined, as in for any value of $\theta$, the function is a constant value.

I then created a program in [GBD Online](https://www.onlinegdb.com/) to recheck if this was actually correct or just a software error. The program iterated $f(\theta)$ for all values of $\theta$ from $1$ to $999$ . And again, surprisingly, the values approached the constant of $0.739085$

The specifics of the program is [here](https://onlinegdb.com/F3h0QI9Je).

The graph in question is shown in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FrmR.png).

My questions for this post are -

1. Why does the function approach a constant?
2. Do all trigonometric functions approach a constant with infinite iterations?
3. If not, why only cosine?

Comment: The reason lies in Banach's fixpoint theorem.

Comment: The number you approach is called the [Dottie number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dottie_number). It is known to be transcendental due to the [Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).

Comment: The sine-iteration converges to the boring value $0$.

Comment: Most of your questions have been answered elsewhere. **(3)**, however, has not. The answer is no, not all do. In fact only sine and cosine even behave well when you compose them many times because the other trig functions have asymptotes.

Comment: essentially you are finding the solution of the equation $x=\cos x$ using iteration

Answer (score 2):

[image]

What is happening is that we can see in the repeated series a converging spiraling iterative solution for

$$ y= \cos(x). $$